# Mysql Issue with triggers with calculation

Tags: mysql

When I try to add a trigger if some value of my table are edited or changed values I want then to update with the calculation. I wanna know if it's possible. And one more question, using a trigger to have a field if not fill to auto calc that value depending on other field is it possible?

My database schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE `testescal` (
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Line` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Brand` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Code` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Quantidade` INT(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Gpl` DECIMAL(60,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`TotalGPL` DECIMAL(50,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ChangeR` DECIMAL(50,0) NOT NULL,
`Unitario` DECIMAL(50,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`TotalUnitario` DECIMAL(50,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`PercOFF` DECIMAL(50,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=7
```

The trigger for update values:

```
BEGIN
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `calci`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-04-05 15:57:43'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT ''
DO BEGIN
Update TotalUnitario
Set New.TotalUnitario= New.Quantidade *New.Unitario;
Update TotalGPL
Set New.TotalGPL= New.Quantidade* New.Gpl;
Update PercOFF
Set New.PercOFF= 100- (New.Unitario*New.ChangeR)/New.Gpl*100;
END
```

The trigger with the main calculation:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `testescal_before_insert` 
       BEFORE               INSERT ON `testescal` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 Set New.TotalUnitario= New.Quantidade *New.Unitario;
 Set New.TotalGPL= New.Quantidade* New.Gpl;
 Set New.PercOFF= 100- (New.Unitario*New.ChangeR)/New.Gpl*100;
 END
```

Comment: yes, what you seek to accomplish is possible. Not sure if your code will accomplish it, but to answer your question, it is possible.

Comment: can you give some tips? please ... THANKS

Comment: Please try to explain a little more in details what you are trying to achive. Keep in mind, we don't know the schema of your database.

Comment: My database schema i've posted ... i was trying to achieve auto calculation with trigger... and having a 2 fields ... one of then is depends on calculation .. the other is inserted field... the thing i am trying to achieve is if you have the value of the calculated field to make the inserted field calculation? is it possible?